Issue while loading a Gdiplus::Bitmap of PixelFormat8bppIndexed into an open cv::mat
I am trying to load an Gdiplus bitmap of 8 bit depth to an opencv mat. the image is in greyscale.
Greyscale Image of 8bit:
.
this is the VC++ code snippet I am using to convert it into cv::mat. But using this when I convert I am getting a faded image of the original image in the cv::mat. What could be the reason?
// Creating the m_Bitmap 
Gdiplus::Bitmap bit(152, 152, PixelFormat8bppIndexed);
m_Bitmap = bit.Clone(0, 0, bit.GetWidth(), bit.GetHeight(), PixelFormat8bppIndexed);

// Later Different paths are added to this bitmap

// Converting this bitmap to cv::mat
Gdiplus::PixelFormat format = m_Bitmap->GetPixelFormat();
if (format == PixelFormat8bppIndexed)
{
            Gdiplus::BitmapData bitmapData;
            Gdiplus::Rect rect(0, 0, width, height);
            m_Bitmap->LockBits(&rect, Gdiplus::ImageLockModeRead, format, &bitmapData);
            
            cv::Mat nmat = cv::Mat(height, width, CV_8UC1, static_cast<unsigned char*>(bitmapData.Scan0), bitmapData.Stride).clone();
}

Original bitmap Image (m_Bitmap):

This is the image preview of cv::mat nmat:

I need to have the same image as the source to be loaded into the cv::mat but that is not happening here.
Note:
When the bitmap was in PixelFormat32bppARGB
The below approach has made the correct conversion and the data in the cv::mat was proper. (like there was no fading thing)
    // Lock the gdiplus::bitmap object to get direct access to the pixel data
    Gdiplus::BitmapData bitmapData;
    Gdiplus::Rect rect(0, 0, width, height);
    m_Bitmap->LockBits(&rect, Gdiplus::ImageLockModeRead, format, &bitmapData);

    // Create a cv::Mat object with the same dimensions and type as the gdiplus::bitmap object
    cv::Mat nmat = cv::Mat(height, width, CV_8UC4, static_cast<unsigned char*>(bitmapData.Scan0), bitmapData.Stride).clone();

    // Convert to single channel image for performing open::CV operations
    cv::Mat singleChannelImage;
    cv::cvtColor(nmat, singleChannelImage, cv::COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);


    m_Bitmap->UnlockBits(&bitmapData);



Are you sure nmat actually has "faded" pixels (and it's not misrepresentation in the debug preview display) ? you can use cv::imwrite to save to file and check.

You cannot directly copy data from gdi+ bitmap which has indexed format into cv::Mat because you then copy indices instead colors to which indices refer. Your gdi+ bitmap has indices + colors palette (from palette by indices you read colors). [1] Convert gdi+ bitmap into PixelFormat24bppRGB by LockBits. [2] Create from this data cv::Mat. [3] Use cv::cvtColor to convert 3 channels image into one - grayscale.

@rafix07 isn't the index just a 1 to 1 trivial mapping in case of 8 bit grayscale ? (i.e. the index is the same as the grayscale ?)

@wohlstad I could not find any information you write about in offical Gdi+ reference (it could be the best to work in such way i.e index is value of grayscale), that is why I put my comment :)

@rafix07 I am actually not sure as well ... I was looking for a 8 bit pixel format without indexing but didn't find one. I read somewhere this speculation that it is not needed for 8 bit grayscale because the mapping is trivial, but as I said I'm not sure.

@wohlstad it is not faded in debug preview, it loaded the same way, after reading to cv::mat i need to do the extraction of the white , blacks and grey. This extraction itself is not working on the nmat. (using cv::inRange)

ok i will try that out @rafix07

I also could not find any direct references to this problem. it used to work for we when i used when my bitmap was in PixelFormat32bppARGB.

@wohlstad All bitmap images with a color depth of 8 bpp or less are indexed. It is technically impossible to create an indexed bitmap without a color table. The size of the color table is encoded in the BITMAPINFOHEADER's biClrUsed field, where a value of 0 is interpreted as the maximum number of entries for the given bit depth.

@IInspectable does it mean that there is no GDI+ image pixel format for 8 bit graylevel (without indexing) ? I thought it is quite a basic and common format (being an opencv user).

@wohlstad The BMP file format doesn't support non-indexed 8bpp images. Once you have an array of bytes in memory a program can interpret it any way it chooses (e.g., as 8-bit grayscale intensities). It doesn't look like GDI+' Bitmap class offers an interface to produce this encoding, though.

@IInspectable I see. That is unfortunate.

so, emulate 8-bit grayscale by giving the 8-bit grayscale image an identity palette. for sure that format supports a palette of that size, no?

@rafix07 i tried out you approach and it worked! Thanks for clarification. I have added my solution to the main post.

This worked for me

Convert gdi+ bitmap into PixelFormat24bppRGB by LockBits.
Create    from this data cv::Mat.
Use cv::cvtColor to convert channels    image into one - grayscale

as suggested by @rafix07
Gdiplus::PixelFormat format = m_Bitmap->GetPixelFormat();
if (format == PixelFormat8bppIndexed)
{  
// Step 1: Convert GDI+ bitmap into PixelFormat24bppRGB
        
Gdiplus::Bitmap tempBitmap24(width, height, PixelFormat24bppRGB);
Gdiplus::Graphics g(&tempBitmap24);
Gdiplus::Rect rect(0, 0, width, height);
        
g.DrawImage(m_Bitmap, rect);
            
    
// Step 2: Create cv::Mat from the converted data               
cv::Mat nmat(height, width, CV_8UC3);
        
for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)                
{               
for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)                 
{                       
Gdiplus::Color pixelColor;                      
tempBitmap24.GetPixel(x, y, &pixelColor);                   
cv::Vec3b& pixel = nmat.at<cv::Vec3b>(y, x);                    
pixel[0] = pixelColor.GetBlue();                        
pixel[1] = pixelColor.GetGreen();                   
pixel[2] = pixelColor.GetRed();         
}           
}
        
cv::Mat singleChannelImage;
// Step 3: Convert 3-channel image into grayscale
cv::cvtColor(nmat, singleChannelImage, cv::COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);

}

